# history-substring-search-end:13: _zsh_highlight: function definition file not found

Tags: zsh

I think I have managed to mess my zsh shell. I am getting the following message when I use the up or down arrow keys:

> "_history-substring-search-end:13: _zsh_highlight: function definition file not found"

Just to give you some background:

I installed antigen using

```
curl https://cdn.rawgit.com/zsh-users/antigen/v1.4.0/bin/antigen.zsh > antigen.zsh
source antigen.zs
```

This worked fine.

Someone mentioned to install it via brew, so I installed it via brew. This is when antigen stopped working and the highlighter.

I tried installing antigen again via

```
curl https://cdn.rawgit.com/zsh-users/antigen/v1.4.0/bin/antigen.zsh > antigen.zsh
source antigen.zs
```

Antigen works while I am in the shell, but the highlighter is not working.

But when I re-launch a new shell and type the antigen command, I receive the following message:

> "zsh: command not found: anitgen"

And also the following message when I use the up and down arrow keys:

> "_history-substring-search-end:13: _zsh_highlight: function definition file not found"

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have edited your question for formatting. Notice that it generally isn't good form to post the exact same question in multiple places such as here and [GitHub](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/406). You didn't even remove the copy-paste artifacts. Secondly, this is probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow as it isn't really a programming question. Maybe [su] or [unix.se] would be better? Finally, does the error message really say "anitgen"? Typo?

Comment: Thank you for editing it ... yes does mention antigen ...

Comment: But you wrote "an**it**gen", not "antigen", which makes it seem you mis-typed it in the command.

Comment: Sorry I meant Antigen.